# react-native-document-picker not returning anything

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, androidx

Idk whether this is because of the react native version or something else make this happen. So I've just integrating my android app with React Native and migrating to AndroidX. Before I did the integration and migration, this code is perfectly fine, I get the result and everything. But, after the integration and migration, I can only see and click the photo from the image list, there's no result, `console.log()` does not working, and even I don't get any error on `catch` block

I'm using react-native-document-picker from https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker and React Native 0.60.5

I've tried using this different library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-picker, but the issue is same

```
try {
    const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.images],
    });

    console.log(res) //not showing anything

    if (res.size <= 3145728) {// 3 MB 
        dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPE_PICK_PHOTO_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        payload: res,
    });
    } else {
    dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPE_PICK_PHOTO_PROFILE_EXCEED,
        payload: res
    });
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err) //not showing anything

    if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
    // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
    }
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out I forgot to add the function for onActivityResult. This is the code that I used.

```
    private final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SoLoader.init(this,false);
        mReactRootView = new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            startReactNative();
        }
    }

    private void startReactNative() {
        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "NusaTalent", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted");
                } else {
                    startReactNative();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + data);
        mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult( this, requestCode, resultCode, data );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot [@arthur-bachtiar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7243737/arthur-bachtiar) for your solution, all that was required for it to work was this on my case:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
...
}
```

I find really disapointing that to the present day the mantainers of the library have not clarify [this existing issue](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/issues/331) on the repository, nor include any working examples or instructions on the installation steps for this procedure.